# intellij navigate to file stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea

So we have a large project and I use the intellij navigate to file cntrl+shift+n all the time.  I don't know what happened but now when I try and use it - it can't find anything.  I haven't recently installed any plugins or anything.

I've restarted intellij a couple times, checked the little filter icon to make sure I'm not filtering on anything...nothing seems to be working.  Any ideas what I need to do to get it working again?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try [11.1.2 build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP) and `File` | `Invalidate Caches`. If it doesn't help, contact JetBrains support with a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: Invalidating the cache worked great - thanks.  Feel a bit sheepish for not trying that.

Comment: Also worked for me invalidating the cache on Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: "Invalidate the cache" worked for me on WebStorm 2017.2.5

Comment: "Invalidate the cache" worked for me on Intellij Community, thanks

Comment: Did not work for me Intellij Ultimate 2020.2 Evaluation

Answer (score 6):

Also try to verify if some plugins are updated, and disable them to try if some of them is the problem.
In my case it was:
Apache config (.htaccess) support Version 131.61

Comment: Thanx! That was exactly the problem in my case (same plugin and same version)!

Comment: That was my problem too, with v. 172.35

Comment: Thank you. This item fixed my problem with the latest Rider 2023

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your keymap is set to Default. You may be using different keymap, so go to File > Setting and search for Keymap. You can change it there.

Comment: Thanks , that's was my problem !!
Solved

Answer (score 1):

When you press Ctrl+Shift+N the Find Window will pop up, check the filter icon (on top right of the Find Window) on the search box and ensure that the file type you are looking for is checked.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to run an update (Help > Check for updates) and update what was needed (2 plugins)

Answer (score 1):

Close the project. Remove .idea and its related file.
Choose New-> Project from Existing sources -> select your project folder
It should work. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the Webstorm with the **project folder again** sorted it out.

```
File -> New -> Project
```

Just restarting it kept the go to file source pointed to the Webstorm app directory.

Answer (score 0):

I program in rust.
So for me installing the missing rust plug-in solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the project and then reimported it using `maven(right corner of IDE) -> plus icon` to add project again